# How to solve redis SerializationFailedException?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted

2017-02-06 15:46:30.417 ERROR 15953 --- [bio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:188) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:171) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:135) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.omneagate.app.frontBean.ApplicationBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0dc8732
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at 

> Blockquote

org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This issue occurs whenever restart my application

Comment: ClassNotFoundException...

Comment: All the classes are available in exact package., It occurs only when i am restarting my server with existing session alive in browser